# Authorship of alternative or fictional personalities

Tags: authorship, personal-name

Let's say I'm a student with a dissociative identity or imaginary friend situation that's not going away no matter what, and I feel they contributed to my research and don't want me to take all the credit. Revealing their identity would be awkward if not impossible. What should I do in terms of academic integrity?

Comment: Could you add Camille Nous as an author? https://www.cogitamus.fr/camilleen.html

Comment: @astronat Cool idea! But what if they do have a name? Especially if the name is already used and will have consequences if disclosed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no problem with including a fictional co-author. It has been done in the past. As long as there is no intent to defraud, which is unlikely, there aren't any serious issues, except...

There is a danger that, unless you are already well established in your field, it will be taken as a joke. There is no problem with jokes, in fact, but that may not be your intent.

And, I hope you are working with a professional on any issues with your identity. And if doing this reinforces what may be a disorder (not my field, so no judgments) it might not be wise. Talk to a professional.